# javascript split string function not working

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am trying to split a string:

```
var str = "*HQ,6170930129,V1,185409,A,3132.3228,N,07424.7726,E,000.04,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555#*HQ,6170930129,V1,185413,A,3132.3226,N,07424.7735,E,000.15,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555"

var res = device_data.split('*');
```

But it's not working. it's just displaying this string

```js
  var str = "*HQ,6170930129,V1,185409,A,3132.3228,N,07424.7726,E,000.04,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555#*HQ,6170930129,V1,185413,A,3132.3226,N,07424.7735,E,000.15,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555"

  var res = str.split('*'); 

  console.dir(res)
```

```
,HQ,6170930129,V1,185409,A,3132.3228,N,07424.7726,E,000.04,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555#,HQ,6170930129,V1,185413,A,3132.3226,N,07424.7735,E,000.15,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555
```

Instead of creating an array with two elements.

Comment: what is the expected result? because I'm pretty sure it's working, just not doing what you think it should do.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added

Comment: @mpm I have added

Comment: Well it is working you have 2 '\*' in your string. split('*') returns an array of 3 elements, not a string. "It" displays a string because this is how an array is converted to a string, elements separated by periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you want something like this:

```js
var str = "*HQ,6170930129,V1,185409,A,3132.3228,N,07424.7726,E,000.04,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555#*HQ,6170930129,V1,185413,A,3132.3226,N,07424.7735,E,000.15,000,280618,FBFFBBFF,410,04,08028,40555"

splitStrArr = str.split('*').filter(str => str != "")

console.log(splitStrArr)
console.log(splitStrArr[0])
console.log(splitStrArr[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a string with a period in the beginning because whatever you are doing leads to the result of String#split being converted to a string. String#split returns an array. An array converted to a string is of the form of element0,element1,element2 ... elements separated by commas.

The result of String#split in your case is ["",...] with 3 elements since your string begins with the character '*' you are searching, so String#split will create an empty string as the first element of the returned array. So the result is exactly as expected, and String#split is working as intended.

get rid of the first character of the string,

```
mystring.substr(1).split('*')
```

get rid of the empty strings

```
mystring.split('*').filter(s=>s!='')
```

to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- var res = str.split("#");

You can check in Javascript console in browser itself.

As a suggestion/ idea, you can always use the browser console, for example, Chrome browser, to execute simple scripts like these.

This way, you can save time, as it is easier to check your data structures, their internal data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
var res = str.split('*');
```

you obtain three elements:
res[0] is '' (empty string)
res[1] is 'HQ,61...'
res[2] is 'HQ,...'